# RBM pretraining weights from Hinton paper code for weights of MATLAB native feedforwardnet toolbox

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, autoencoder, rbm, feed-forward

I want to use RBM pretraining weights from Hinton paper code for weights of MATLAB native feedforwardnet toolbox. 
Anyone can help me how to set or arrange the pre-trained weight for feedforwardnet?

for instance, i used Hinton code from http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/MatlabForSciencePaper.html

and use the pre-trained weights for matlab feedforwardnet.

```
W=hintonRBMpretrained;

net=feedforwardnet([700 300 200 30 200 300 700]);

net.setwb(net,W);
```

how to set up or arrange the W such that it will match the feedforwardnet structure? I know how to use single vector but i am afraid that the order or the weights sequence is incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB [`feedforwardnet`](https://mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/feedforwardnet.html) function returns a *Neural Network* object with the properties as described in the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/neural-network-object-properties.html). The workflow for creating a neural network with pre-trained weights is as follows:

1. Load data
2. Create the network
3. Configure the network
4. Initialize the weights and biases
5. Train the network

The steps 1, 2, 3, and 5 are exactly as they would be when creating a neural network from scratch. Let's look at a simple example:

```
% 1. Load data
load fisheriris
meas = meas.';
species = species.';
targets = dummyvar(categorical(species));

% 2. Create network
net = feedforwardnet([16, 16]);

% 3. Configure the network
configure(net, meas, targets)
```

Now, we have a neural network `net` with 4 inputs (sepal and petal length and width), and 3 outputs ('setosa', 'versicolor', and 'virginica'). We have two hidden layers with 16 nodes each. The weights are stored in the two fields `net.IW` and `net.LW`, where `IW` are the **i**nput **w**eights, and `LW` are the **l**ayer **w**eights:

```
>> net.IW
ans =
  3×1 cell array

    [16×4 double]
    []
    []

>> net.LW
ans =
  3×3 cell array

                []               []    []
    [16×16 double]               []    []
                []    [3×16 double]    []
```

This is confusing at first, but makes sense: each row in both these cell arrays corresponds to one of the layers we have.

In the `IW` array, we have the weights between the input and each of the layers. Obviously, we only have weights between the input and the first layer. The shape of this weight matrix is `16x4`, as we have `4` inputs and `16` hidden units.

In the `LW` array, we have the weights *from* each layer (the rows) *to* each layer (the columns). In our case, we have a `16x16` weight matrix from the first to the second layer, and a `3x16` weight matrix from the second to the third layer. Makes perfect sense, right?

With that, we know how to initialize the weights we have got from the RBM code:

```
net.IW{1,1} = weights_input;
net.LW{2,1} = weights_hidden;
```

With that, you can continue with step 5, i.e. training the network in a supervised fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the problem is i don't know the order of weights from the pre-training. I am afraid the weights are on decreasing index or flipped upside or left-light where the weight size is the same as feedforwardnet weights.

Comment: What i did is i set 'vishid' as input weights without changing the order.